# groupBy that is TypeScript safe

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Given all the answers already out there we tried to create a `groupBy` arrow function that doesn't complain about TypeScript errors. with guidance from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects/46431916#46431916) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects) we already have this working code:

```js
const groupBy = <TItem>(
  items: TItem[],
  key: string
): { [key: string]: TItem[] } =>
  items.reduce(
    (result, item) => ({
      ...result,
      [item[key]]: [...(result[item[key]] || []), item],
    }),
    {}
  )
```

However, it still complains:
[image: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.]

It is indeed possible that the used `key` is empty/blank. So TypeScript is not wrong here. So in that case it should simply use a placeholder value like `NA` or something.

What is the correct way to create a reusable error free typescript version for this `groupBy` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use some generics to lower down the key type and force the object to contain the key:

```
type ObjectKey = string | number | symbol;

const groupBy = <K extends ObjectKey, TItem extends Record<K, ObjectKey>>(
  items: TItem[],
  key: K
): Record<ObjectKey, TItem[]> =>
  items.reduce(
    (result, item) => ({
      ...result,
      [item[key]]: [...(result[item[key]] || []), item],
    }),
    {} as Record<ObjectKey, TItem[]>
  );
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AaQiKBeKBnYAJwEsA7AcygB8pSBXAWzgkOvxCYHsAbAbgCh+yTqQJRyhTnTAAhLLgA8aKBAAewCKQAmeWIhTpMAGigAVAJIaGK9Zp1QASik6EtSk-CSoMIAHy+ACn4oKGIrPAAuM0sIBgBtAF0jYKgAa0wotH4ASiinYVcFTwMfEwsrRN8cXxSw2LwAOkIILTpkCCCQkIDmvDpuYBM6hmzqqACAbxSuqAa53v7B6a644bj0kASEqLi5hp6IPoHVio2t6hpE7KGrJOWAX2vlifuoAENdfJc3Yu9jaIqCRqIWyAiEIjwPAgDW4nHIAQkUlkIACcQmbyiAEYTHAogAme4mdFYnFRADMhKgxKgeNJUApSSgACI3kzsqD+EA)

Comment: Thank you very much! I couldn't figure this out myself.  Works like a charm as long as the `ObjectKey` is not null, but that's easily fixed.

Comment: @henroper ...you don't. The goal is to group the objects by a key, not to change them by removing a key.

Comment: @henroper First of all, it'd be nice if you used a permanent service like pastebin instead of a 24 hour service like privatebin, but also, that's exactly my point. The goal is to group objects by a key, not to remove the grouped key from the objects.